# Https / Certificate not trusted on mobile devices: Nexus 4 & Galaxy S4

Tags: google-app-engine, https

On the computer everything works fine but on mobile I got the following error:

[image: Security]

I use HTTS through Google App Engine

Let me know if you need more info

Comment: I didn't face the problem from my nexus5 device

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On some devices PositiveSSL CA2 is not trusted. But this CA is signed by AddTrustExternalCARoot which should by trusted on all Android devices.

Therefore you can add the intermediate certificate (PositiveSSL CA2) to avoid the error message.

One way to do this is:

Download [PositiveSSL_CA2.crt](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=119&nav=0,4)

```
cat your_domain.crt PositiveSSL_CA2.crt > new.crt
```

Use `new.crt` with GAE as usual.

Comment: Worked like a charm, sorry I took so long I was pretty busy with other things! Thank you again for your answer, I really appreciate!